# Updated App Crashing on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, updates

This is interesting.  I have a Universal app.  The iPhone and iPad versions both share the same Classes, and just have different xib files.  I have been getting frequent reports that after updating the iPad version, it will not run, and simply crashes.  However, updates to the iPhone version work just fine.  Deleting the iPad app, restarting, and reinstalling will fix the crash at startup issue.

Update With Affected Code:

Ok, so after resymbolicating and viewing the affected line of codes, here is all the areas I feel are causing issues.

I wanted the app to ask a question the first time, and ONLY the first time the app was ran, so in the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I have:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (! [defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRun"]) {
    UIAlertView *firstrun = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sermon Preference" message:@"Do you prefer audio only, or video sermons?  (This setting can be changed at any time in the Settings Page.)" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Audio", @"Video", nil];
        [firstrun show];
        [firstrun release];
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notFirstRun"];
}
```

Then I have in the AppDelegate Still:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)       {   
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSString *nope = @"Audio";
            [defaults setObject:nope forKey:@"videosermons"];
            [defaults synchronize];


        }
        if (buttonIndex == 1)        {
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSString *yup = @"Video";
            [defaults setObject:yup forKey:@"videosermons"];
            [defaults synchronize];        }

        }
```

I wanted these values to be changed in a Settings window, so in the Settings class I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


        NSString *currently = [defaults objectForKey:@"videosermons"];

    if ([currently isEqualToString:@"Audio"]) {
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    }
    if ([currently isEqualToString:@"Video"]) {
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    }


    NSString *firstName = [defaults objectForKey:@"firstName"];
    if (firstName  == nil) {

    }
    else {
        myTextField.text = firstName;
    }
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bellavenue.org/worship.html"];
    self.content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The line that the crash log says is causing the crash is:

```
    if ([currently isEqualToString:@"Audio"]) {
```

What all is going on that is causing a crash ONLY on the iPad, and ONLY when updating an already installed previous version, and not a NEW install?

UPDATE CRASH LOG:

```
Incident Identifier: EE5B1A62-12DB-4ED5-95CD-0C68CE1614BA
CrashReporter Key:   92fbea1d35e30ff292ba7362f93548dceedefe66
Hardware Model:      iPad2,5
Process:         Bell Avenue [1013]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/CE1AE921-5767-4B3C-B223-2C098041C73E/Bell Avenue.app/Bell Avenue
Identifier:      Bell Avenue
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-12-01 14:11:10.653 -0600
OS Version:      iOS 6.1 (10B5105c)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3411529e 0x34053000 + 795294
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33f3297a 0x33f2a000 + 35194
2   CoreFoundation                  0x34118e02 0x34053000 + 810498
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3411752c 0x34053000 + 804140
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3406ef64 0x34053000 + 114532
5   Bell Avenue                     0x0008652e -[Settings viewDidLoad] (Settings.m:64)
6   UIKit                           0x3396578c 0x337c5000 + 1705868
7   UIKit                           0x3396d5fa 0x337c5000 + 1738234
8   UIKit                           0x3399786a 0x337c5000 + 1910890
9   UIKit                           0x33820ae4 0x337c5000 + 375524
10  UIKit                           0x337c8f7c 0x337c5000 + 16252
11  UIKit                           0x337c8a10 0x337c5000 + 14864
12  UIKit                           0x337c845e 0x337c5000 + 13406
13  GraphicsServices                0x3afaf59e 0x3afa9000 + 26014
14  GraphicsServices                0x3afaf1ce 0x3afa9000 + 25038
15  CoreFoundation                  0x340ea16e 0x34053000 + 618862
16  CoreFoundation                  0x340ea112 0x34053000 + 618770
17  CoreFoundation                  0x340e8f94 0x34053000 + 614292
18  CoreFoundation                  0x3405beb8 0x34053000 + 36536
19  CoreFoundation                  0x3405bd44 0x34053000 + 36164
20  UIKit                           0x3381f7c8 0x337c5000 + 370632
21  UIKit                           0x3381c644 0x337c5000 + 357956
22  Bell Avenue                     0x000832fe main (main.m:13)
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x39d7ab1c 0x39d79000 + 6940


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385b6350 0x385a5000 + 70480
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a64d11e 0x3a61e000 + 192798
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a68996e 0x3a61e000 + 440686
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33e1cd4a 0x33e19000 + 15690
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33e19ff4 0x33e19000 + 4084
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33f32a74 0x33f2a000 + 35444
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33e1a078 0x33e19000 + 4216
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33e1a110 0x33e19000 + 4368
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33e1b594 0x33e19000 + 9620
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33f329cc 0x33f2a000 + 35276
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3405bf1c 0x34053000 + 36636
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3405bd44 0x34053000 + 36164
12  UIKit                           0x3381f7c8 0x337c5000 + 370632
13  UIKit                           0x3381c644 0x337c5000 + 357956
14  Bell Avenue                     0x000832fe main (main.m:13)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x39d7ab1c 0x39d79000 + 6940

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385b6d98 0x385a5000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a624cf6 0x3a61e000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a624a12 0x3a61e000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a6248a0 0x3a61e000 + 26784

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385a6648 0x385a5000 + 5704
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3aee2974 0x3aeda000 + 35188
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3aee2654 0x3aeda000 + 34388

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385b6d98 0x385a5000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a624cf6 0x3a61e000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a624a12 0x3a61e000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a6248a0 0x3a61e000 + 26784

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385b60fc 0x385a5000 + 69884
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a61f124 0x3a61e000 + 4388
2   WebCore                         0x38db41c0 0x38da8000 + 49600
3   WebCore                         0x38db40f2 0x38da8000 + 49394
4   CoreFoundation                  0x340ea6ca 0x34053000 + 620234
5   CoreFoundation                  0x340e89bc 0x34053000 + 612796
6   CoreFoundation                  0x340e8de8 0x34053000 + 613864
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3405beb8 0x34053000 + 36536
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3405bd44 0x34053000 + 36164
9   WebCore                         0x38db22a8 0x38da8000 + 41640
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a62f30e 0x3a61e000 + 70414
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a62f1d4 0x3a61e000 + 70100
```

Comment: Try to get crash reports or at least console logs in order to look for hints.  Anything less is random guessing.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no crash reports in iTunes Connect, and don't have any older versions on my iPads to do an updte and run in xcode

Comment: Perhaps the App Store was serving corrupted binaries.  It does that every once in a while.

Comment: @PhillipMills I have a quite lengthy crash report, but am unsure exactly how to use it to pinpoint where the issue is at.

Comment: @user717452: Drag the crash report into the organizer "Device Logs" to get it symbolicated. And then post the complete report as part of your question. Only having the exception type doesn't help.

Comment: @Kerni Issue is the report I got was just from a friend who merely copied and pasted from diagnostics & usage in their iPad to me.

Comment: @user717452: You need the complete report. E.g. let him sync the iPad with iTunes, then the crash report is in the file system of the Mac/PC. There are plenty of places where it shows how to find the file then depending on the operation system on SO and any search engine.

Comment: @Kerni Ok, I added the report

Comment: You're getting closer.  :)  Here's a tech note about resolving symbols: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-ANALYZING_CRASH_REPORTS-SYMBOLICATION

Comment: The app was downloaded from the appstore and that is what showed up when i drug the .dSYM file to Xcode.  What am i MISSIN?

Comment: Ok, I resymbolicated and got what is shown in edited question.

Comment: @PhillipMills I have updated the original question quite a bit with code from the app.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Kerni Updated question with more code

Comment: @user717452: we need to see the crash log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system caused the app to abort (`SIGABRT`). There are several issues in the code:

1. All code in `viewDidLoad` should be actually executed in `viewWillAppear:`. None of the code is relevant to be executed when the view is loaded by iOS.
2. `self.content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url]` is a synchronous call, blocking the main thread for how ever long this takes. You should either call this asynchronously or use an NSOperationQueue to load the content and then set it on the main thread again. Right now this blocks the loading process of the view controller, which is an ever worse idea to do.
3. The exception message is not shown, but I suspect you the `currently` object is not of type `NSString` and it gets an `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error.

You may want to read this series about how to read and work with crash reports: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: I did some more testing and got this in console:

[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d58d528

Comment: So the value you get from userdefaults is a `Bool` value, and not a `NSString` as you expect. Maybe in a previous version you did use `Bool` for the same key?

Comment: For some reason the value it is returning for that key is 0 when I'm expecting either a string value of audio or video

Comment: The code that has always been used is:


if (buttonIndex == 0)  { 
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSString *nope = @"Audio";
            [defaults setObject:nope forKey:@"videosermons"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            
            
        }
        if (buttonIndex == 1)        {
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSString *yup = @"Video";
            [defaults setObject:yup forKey:@"videosermons"];
            [defaults synchronize];        }
    
     }

Comment: If I move this section of code from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear, it works fine.  Why is this?

Comment: For the concrete reasons you should probably ask Apple engineers :) `viewDidLoad` isn't meant to be used for such kind of code as it is also being called very very early when loading the view controller into memory.

Comment: Just odd that with it running in viewDidLoad, it will crash on updates to apps, but new installs won't

Comment: It is. Make sure to change that loading call to be asynchronous too! And since you solved the issues with this input, it would be nice to accept this answer.